# Moving code to older version of ECMAScript

Tags: javascript

I am completely new to ECMA script and also JavaScript in general.

I'm trying to convert my code to work on an older version of ECMA script (I think).

The following code

```
Unit.prototype.getItems = function (...args) {
        let item = this.getItem.apply(this, args), items = [];
    
        if (item) {
            do {
                items.push(copyUnit(item));
            } while (item.getNext());
        }
    
        return items;
    };
```

Returns:

```
SyntaxError: missing formal parameter on the first line.
```

What does the ...args argument mean? What code can I replace it with to be compatible with the older version of ECMA script.

Comment: What is this code going to run in? Do you know what version of ECMAScript?

Comment: Have a look at https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-parameters. In general you can either make Babel part of your build process, or use https://babeljs.io/repl to transpile specific parts.

Comment: It's a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters). There is no direct analogue before ES2015, but the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) is close.

Comment: That said, it's a **really** old JavaScript environment that doesn't support rest parameters. Unless you need your code to run in, say, IE11, you shouldn't have to stop using them. What enviroment are you targeting?